# Improve this possible 5 joins SQL sentence

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, join

I'm using MySQL 5, and I need to do this sentence to get the results. It's the first attempt when I think about it. I know there are several ways to improve it, but I want to get your opinions first:

```
SELECT p.id, p.image, p.lat, p.lng, 
       p.category_id, p2.title, p2.description, c2.name
FROM place p
LEFT JOIN place_translation p2 ON p.id = p2.id
LEFT JOIN trip_place t ON p.id = t.place_id
LEFT JOIN category c ON p.category_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN category_translation c2 ON c.id = c2.id
WHERE c.root_id =1
AND c2.lang =  'en'
AND p2.lang =  'en'
AND t.trip_id =1
AND p.root_id =1
AND p.lft >39
AND p.rgt <44
ORDER BY p2.title
```

It's a multilingual service, so we have `place_translation` and `category_translation`. We get the places that belongs to a trip and that belongs to a city (it's a nested set, so `root_id`, `lft` and `rgt`)

The indexes are:

```
on table place: id, category_id
on table place_translation: id-lang index
on table trip_place: place_id, trip_id
on table category: id
on table category_translation: id-lang index
```

So, with your experience, how would you improve it to make it smaller? I know I don't have to denormalized until I have problems; but I want to fix a good base.

thanks!

Comment: what indexes do you have on the respective tables?

Comment: on table place: id, category_id
on table place_translation: id-lang index
on table trip_place: place_id, trip_id
on table category: id
on table category_translation: id-lang index

Comment: @fesja: suggest you edit question with index info...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two obvious things. Since you have conditions on values from each table in `WHERE`, you require that you found matching rows in the `JOIN` clauses. This means you should use inner joins, not left outer joins. Next, to filter the results as soon as possible you can move some of the conditions from `WHERE` to `JOIN .. ON`.

I've also reordered the tables in a way that makes sense to me, i.e. first you are selecting from `trip_place`, because you know you want only places from this trip. Then for each row from `trip_place` find the matching `place`, and for each `place` find the matching `category`. Translations are last because they don't affect the query functionally. So the query would be something like this:

```
SELECT
    p.id, p.image, p.lat, p.lng, 
    p.category_id, p2.title, p2.description, c2.name
FROM
    trip_place t
    JOIN place p ON p.id = t.place_id AND p.root_id = 1 AND p.lft > 39 AND p.rgt < 44
    JOIN category c ON p.category_id = c.id AND c.root_id = 1
    JOIN place_translation p2 ON p.id = p2.id AND p2.lang = 'en'
    JOIN category_translation c2 ON c.id = c2.id AND c2.lang = 'en'
WHERE
    t.trip_id = 1
ORDER BY p2.title
```

I can't tell if it's actually faster, but it might be. You should run `EXPLAIN` on both of them. From the look at the list of indexes, you should probably add an index on `place (root_id, p.lft, p.rgt)` (all of them as a single index, not each column individually).

Comment: thanks Lukáš, I have already added the index you told me and another one in category: root_id

Your sentence takes a bit less time (0.0018 against 0.0020) but it makes much more sense. So I suppose when I have thousands of rows it will be bigger the difference

thanks!